# dependent:destroy seems not working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following problem . I have the models bus_routes and break_points. A BusRoute has 2  breakPoints
I created the following relationships

```
class BusRoute < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :destination_id, :origen_id
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: "BreakPoint"
  belongs_to :origen, class_name: "BreakPoint"
end

class BreakPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city,:province_id,:province  

end
```

I need that if I eliminate an BreakPoint any record in BusRoute destination_id  or origen_id
that have the id of the breakPoint eliminated is eliminated of the database with dependent: :destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following will work:

```
class BreakPoint < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :destinations,
            foreign_key: :destination_id,
            class_name: 'BusRoute',
            dependent: :destroy

  has_many :origens,
            foreign_key: :origen_id,
            class_name: 'BusRoute',
            dependent: :destroy

end
```

Comment: Thanks friend. This worked perfect. Only changed some lines of code but that is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

any record in BusRoute  can't have the id of the breakPoint eliminated.
Becouse BusRoute has BreakPoint, but not BreakPoint has BusRoute.
in BreakPoint must be bus_route_id.
BusRoute has not break_point_id.